# How to Disable Snackbar on Tab change in TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-snackbar

When application is started I am showing `Snackbar` if Internet connection is not available in my `TabLayout` Fragments.I have added Retry action to Snackbar to check for Internet.If Retry is pressed and Internet connection gets available Snackbar is dismiss but if internet connection is available and I switch the tabs the Snackbar is not dismissed. Again I need to press Retry Action button and then Snackbar is dismiss.How to resolve this ?
This is code for `checkInternet`

```
public void checkInternet(){
       String NetworkStatus = biz.fyra.bookapp.utils.NetworkStatus.checkConnection(getContext());
       if (NetworkStatus.equals("false")) {
          snackbar=Snackbar.make(recyclerView,"You are Offline.",
                  Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Retry", new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
             checkInternet();
              }
          });
          snackbar.show();
       }else{
           getData();
       }

   }
```

This is code to display my `TabLayout` Fragments

```
public class ChooseTab extends Fragment  {

    // Tab Layout and ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    public ChooseTab() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_tab, container, false);
        int position=getArguments().getInt("TARGET_FRAGMENT_ID");
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("QUEUE"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TABLES"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Reservation"));
        viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.simpleViewPager);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

How to disable Snackbar if Tab is changed and  Internet is already available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the fragment is called when ViewPager has finished its setup, i.e adding the fragments from its adapter and displaying the fragments.

So you need to show Snackbar if only the fragment is visible or vice versa.

if you use support library for fragments, then you can use getUserVisibleHint() or override setUserVisibleHint() to check for fragment visibility.

You can do the following:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
  ...
  @Override
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
     if (isVisibleToUser) {
       // show snake bar here.
     } else {
    }
  }
   ...
}
```

Comment: I have put the code  `@Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
        if (menuVisible) {
            if(snackbar!=null && snackbar.isShown()){
                snackbar.dismiss();
            }
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    checkInternet();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }` but not working